# Why does Java Language Specification say that the expression (n > 2) is not a constant expression?

Tags: java

In the Java Language Specifications chapter on [Definite Assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html), the [Example 16-2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html#d5e30957) says that

> A Java compiler must produce a compile-time error for the code:
>
> ```
> {
>     int k;
>     int n = 5;
>     if (n > 2)
>         k = 3;
>     System.out.println(k);  /* k is not "definitely assigned"
>                                before this statement */ 
> }
> ```
>
> even though the value of n is known at compile time, and in principle
>   it can be known at compile time that the assignment to k will always
>   be executed (more properly, evaluated). A Java compiler must operate
>   according to the rules laid out in this section. The rules recognize
>   only constant expressions; in this example, **the expression n > 2 is
>   not a constant expression as defined in §15.28.**

But, if we look at §15.28, it says that

> the relational operators <, <=, >, and >=

can contribute to a constant expression.

Is the expression `n > 2` a constant expression or not? How can we determine this?

Comment: Is `n` is a constant expression? Nope.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It says so because `n` is not a [constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive
>   type or a `String` that does not complete abruptly and is composed using
>   only the following:
>
> - [...]
> - Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to [constant variables (§4.12.4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4).

and

> A constant variable is a `final` variable of primitive type or type
>   `String` that is initialized with a constant expression (§15.28).

`n` is not `final` and therefore isn't a constant variable. It therefore isn't a constant expression. And therefore `n < 2` is not a constant expression.

Comment: So, a local variable name is not a constant variable, I miss the simple names part. Now I understand, thx Sotirios !

Comment: @reinardhz No. You misunderstood. The problem isn't the name, it's the fact that the variable isn't `final`.

Comment: So, any variable that is not final is not a constant variable right?

Comment: @reinardhz If it's not `final`, it can't be a constant variable. But there are other rules for deciding if a variable is a constant variable. Those are laid out in the JLS chapter linked.

Answer (score 1):

You've misread §15.28 of the spec. That section lists the language elements that are permissible in a constant expression. If the expression has anything **not** on the list, then it is not a constant expression. It does **not** mean (as you apparently read it to mean) that if any of the elements in the list is present then the expression is constant.

From the language spec (emphasis added):

> A *constant expression* is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a `String` that does not complete abruptly and is composed using **only** the following:
>   ... etc.

The expression `n > 2` is not a constant expression because `n` is not declared `final` and hence `n` is not a constant. Even though its value at that point in the code can only be 5, that does not conform to the language definition of a constant. (See [§4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4), which is referenced by §15.28.)